# Reference Error: function not difined

Tags: jquery

I am creating a jQuery, but i get an error message saying:

> "ReferenceError: display_results_table is not defined".

Im not sure why its undefined or how to define it, any help would be great thanks!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function display_results_table(){
            $("maintable").empty();
            $('<table id = "results_table">').appendTo('#maintable');
            $.get("sam.php", {ISO_id: $('#ISO_id').val(), queryType: $('#differentOptions').val()},

        function(results_obtained){

            $('<tr><td>ISO_id</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');

            for( var i = 0; i results_obtained.length; i++){
                $('<tr><td>' + results_obtained[i].ISO_id + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');
            },'json');
            $('</table>').appendTo('#maintable');


        };


    </script>
    <title>sam.htm</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
    <table>
        <td><input name="ISO_id" id="ISO_id" value="GBR" type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="submit" onClick="display_results_table()"/></td>
    </table>
</form>
<div id="maintable"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Because your JS code has at least one syntax error, which means the code cannot be executed, so the function does not exist. Learn how to debug JavaScript: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Your first function is not closed and the second section is never used. Or maybe it's never closed. There are several syntax errors in your script.

Comment: Also, how do you plan on using the second anonymous function? It doesn't appear to do anything. - nm it's the success callback. Didn't see that immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Just because I have had DUH moments when I notice a big mistake I made, I decided to correct this for you with how I think you meant to have it. Again, you just seem to have some severe syntax issues:

```
function display_results_table() {
    $("maintable").empty();
    $('<table id = "results_table">').appendTo('#maintable');
    $.get("sam.php", { ISO_id: $('#ISO_id').val(), queryType: $('#differentOptions').val() }, function (results_obtained) {

        $('<tr><td>ISO_id</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');

        for (var i = 0; i <= results_obtained.length; i++) {
            $('<tr><td>' + results_obtained[i].ISO_id + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#results_table');
        }
    }, 'json');

    $('</table>').appendTo('#maintable');
}
```